# Solve initial-boundary value problem of heat equation without NDSolve or DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following pde

```
pde = D[u[t, x], t] - D[u[t, x], x, x] == 0
```

with the boundary conditions defined as

```
bc = {u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 1] == 0, u[0, x] == 0}
```

However, I just learned the separation of variables in class and this kind of pde is not discussed in my textbook. I am wondering how I can solve it without using `DSolve` or `NDSolve`?

Comment: One would expect `DSolve[{pde, bc}, u, {x, t}]` to  provide a symbolic solution, but it returns unevaluated.  `NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 4}]` gives a numerical solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: "I just learned the separation of variables in class and this kind of pde is not discussed in my textbook. " Well, then I should say the introduction for separation of variables in your textbook is too brief.

Answer (score 4):

Here is analytical solution using eigenfunction expansion method.

```
Clear[x, t, a, b, an, sol, L0, k, qn, uEquib]
pde = Hold[D[u[t, x], t] - D[u[t, x], x, x] == 0];

(* find equilibrium solution, from setting D[u[t,x],t]=0*)
uEquib = a x + b; 
uEquib = uEquib /. First@Solve[{(uEquib /. x -> 0) == Sin[t],
         (uEquib /. x -> L0 ) == 0}, {a, b}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*use known eigenfunction for homogenouse heat PDE*)
eigFunction = Sin[n Pi x /L0]; 
pde = ReleaseHold[pde /. u[t, x] -> (an[t] eigFunction + uEquib)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*replace the new source by eigenfunction expansion*)
pde = pde /. (D[uEquib, t] -> qn eigFunction)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 (*find qn by orthogonality*)
 qn = 2/L0 Assuming[Element[n, Integers], Integrate[ D[uEquib, t] eigFunction, {x, 0, L0}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*initial conditions, since v=u-r and u at t=0 is zero*)
ic = uEquib /. t -> 0 

(*solve for an[t]*)
c = an[t] /. First@DSolve[{pde, an[0] == ic}, an[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
L0 = 1; (*length*)
sol[t_, x_, k_] := Evaluate[Sum[ c eigFunction + uEquib , {n, 1, k}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plot the solution for 15 terms

```
Plot3D[sol[t, x, 15], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {x, 0, L0}, AxesLabel -> {t, x, u}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Complete code in one block

```
Clear[x, t, a, b, an, sol, L0, k, qn, uEquib]
pde = Hold[D[u[t, x], t] - D[u[t, x], x, x] == 0];
(* equilibrium solution, from setting D[u[t,x],t]=0*)
uEquib = a x + b;         
uEquib = uEquib /. First@Solve[{(uEquib /. x -> 0) == Sin[t], (uEquib /. x -> L0 ) == 0}, {a, b}];
eigFunction = Sin[n Pi x /L0]; 
pde = ReleaseHold[pde /. u[t, x] -> (an[t] eigFunction + uEquib)];
(*replace the new source by eigenfunction expansion*)
pde = pde /. (D[uEquib, t] -> qn eigFunction) ;
(*find qn by orthogonality*)
qn = 2/L0 Assuming[Element[n, Integers],Integrate[ D[uEquib, t] eigFunction, {x, 0, L0}]]; 
(*initial conditions, since v=u-r and u at t=0 is zero*)
ic = uEquib /. t -> 0; 
(*solve for an[t]*)
c = an[t] /. First@DSolve[{pde, an[0] == ic}, an[t], t]; 
L0 = 1;
sol[t_, x_, k_] := Evaluate[Sum[ c eigFunction + uEquib , {n, 1, k}]]
Plot3D[sol[t, x, 15], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {x, 0, L0}, AxesLabel -> {t, x, u}]
```

Animation:

```
    Animate[Plot[sol[t, x, 10], {x, 0, L0}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, L0}, {-10, 10}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"u[x,t]", None}, {"x", 
     Row[{"time = ", NumberForm[N@t, {3, 2}], " seconds"}]}}], {t, 0, 
  20, 1/10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on Laplace transform. First transform the equation and b.c.s and substitute the i.c. into them:

```
pde = D[u[t, x], t] - D[u[t, x], x, x] == 0;
ic = {u[0, x] == 0};
bc = {u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 1] == 0};

teqn = LaplaceTransform[{pde, bc}, t, s] /. Rule @@@ ic /. 
   HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a /. u -> (U[#2] &)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here `U[x]` denotes Laplace transform of `u[t, x]`, I make this change because `DSolve` can't handle expression involving `LaplaceTransform` directly.

The next step is to solve the ODE and obtain the transformed solution:

```
tsol = DSolve[teqn, U[x], x][[1, 1, -1]]
```

Oops… I still use `DSolve` for solving the ODE, but I guess what you mean in the question is "not to solve the PDE with `DSolve` or `NDSolve` **directly**", right?

The last step is to do the inverse Laplace transform, but `InverseLaplaceTransform` can't handle `tsol` directly, luckily this can be circumvented by expanding `tsol` with Fourier sine series first:

```
easyFourierSinCoefficient[expr_, t_, {a_, b_}, n_] := 
 FourierSinCoefficient[expr /. t -> t + a, t, n, 
   FourierParameters -> {1, Pi/(b - a)}] /. t -> t - a

easyTerm[t_, {a_, b_}, n_] := Sin[Pi/(b - a) n (t - a)]

coe = easyFourierSinCoefficient[tsol, x, {0, 1}, n]

term = easyTerm[x, {0, 1}, n]

solterm = InverseLaplaceTransform[coe term, s, t]
```

The solution is a summation of `solterm` from `1` to `Infinity`:

```
sol = HoldForm[Sum[#, {n, Infinity}]] &@solterm
```

> $$u(t,x)=\sum _n^{\infty } 2 n \pi  \left(\frac{e^{-n^2 \pi ^2 t}}{1+n^4 \pi ^4}+\frac{-\cos (t)+n^2 \pi ^2 \sin (t)}{1+n^4 \pi ^4}\right) \sin (n \pi  x)$$

I'm still in *v9*, you can use `Inactivate` in or after *v10* instead of `HoldForm`.

---

With the help of [`finiteFourierSinTransform`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155818/1871), I can now add a solution that doesn't make use of `DSolve`. We just need to:

1. Make finite Fourier sine transform:

   ```
   {teq, tic} = 
    finiteFourierSinTransform[{pde, ic}, {x, 0, 1}, n] /. Rule @@@ bc /. 
     HoldPattern@finiteFourierSinTransform[a_, __] :> a
   ```
2. Make Laplace transform:

   ```
   tteq = LaplaceTransform[teq, t, s] /. Rule @@@ tic
   ```
3. Solve for the transformed solution:

   ```
   ttsol = Solve[tteq, LaplaceTransform[u[t, x], t, s]][[1, 1, -1]]
   ```
4. Transform back:

   ```
   tsol = InverseLaplaceTransform[ttsol, s, t]
   sol = inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[tsol, n, {x, 0, 1}]
   ```

The result is same as above.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in a comment, one might hope that `DSolve[{pde, bc}, u, {x, t}]` could handle this problem, but it returns unevaluated.  Although this problem can be solved by Laplace transforms, it is more straightforward to solve it numerically.

```
s = NDSolveValue[{pde, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
Plot3D[s[t, x], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {t, x, u}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please suggest a way to do Laplace Transform? I just do not want to use NDSolve.

Comment: @Daniel  Laplace transform the PDE and `x == 0` boundary condition.  Then, solve the resulting ODE in `x`, and perform the inverse Laplace transform.  Mathematica has commands for all three steps.  If you can wait for about 3 hours, I can take a more thorough look at it.