# Implement finite Fourier transforms

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

Recently I came across finite Fourier transforms, which can be used for solving certain type of boundary value problem (BVP) of linear partial differential equation (PDE) with constant coefficient. The definition of the transforms and their properties are as follows.

Finite Fourier sine transform and its inversion:

$$\mathcal{F}_s \{f (x)\}=\tilde{f}_s(n)=\int_0^a f (x) \sin  (\frac{n\pi x}{a}) \, dx$$
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}_s \{\tilde{f}_s(n)\}=f (x)=\frac{2}{a} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \tilde{f}_s(n) \sin  (\frac{n \pi x}{a}) $$

Finite Fourier cosine transform and its inversion:

$$\mathcal{F}_c \{f (x)\}=\tilde{f}_c(n)=\int_0^a f (x) \cos  (\frac{n\pi x}{a}) \, dx$$
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}_c \{\tilde{f}_c(n)\}=f (x)=\frac{1}{a}\tilde{f}_c(0)+\frac{2}{a} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \tilde{f}_c(n) \cos  (\frac{n \pi x}{a}) $$

Their main properties playing role in PDE solving are:

$$\mathcal{F}_s \{f' (x)\}=-(\frac{n \pi}{a})\tilde{f}_c(n)$$
$$\mathcal{F}_c \{f' (x)\}=(\frac{n \pi}{a})\tilde{f}_s(n)+(-1)^{n}f'(a)-f'(0)$$

For more information you can refer to [this material](http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat417/lecture18.pdf) or Chapter 10 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1482223570).

Can we implement these transforms in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Why not use the setting `FourierParameters -> {-1, π/a}` in  `FourierSinCoefficient[]`, `FourierCosCoefficient[]`, `FourierCosSeries[]`, and `FourierSinSeries[]`?

Comment: Because these formula is given in Lokenath Debnath's book and I feel that copying them from the book is more comfortable than adjusting `FourierCosCoefficient`, and [`Integrate` seems to perform better than `FourierCosCoefficient`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149468/a-more-convenient-fourier-series#comment401406_149469).

Answer (score 14):

This post contains several code blocks, you can copy them easily with the help of [`importCode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/1871).

---

The following is my implementation for finite Fourier transforms. Here I've also implemented finite Fourier transform, which can be viewed as the counterpart of `FourierSeries`:

```
ClearAll[finiteFourierSinTransform, finiteFourierCosTransform, finiteFourierTransform, 
transformToIntegrate]

(#[(h : List | Plus | Equal)[a__], x_, n_] := Function[f, #[f, x, n]] /@ h[a];
    #[a_ b_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, n_] /; FreeQ[b, x] := 
     b #[a, {x, xmin, xmax}, n]) & /@ {finiteFourierSinTransform, 
   finiteFourierCosTransform, finiteFourierTransform};
argumentPattern = (#[
      Derivative[i___, j_, k___][head_][var1___, x_, var2___], {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, n_] /;
      Length@{i} === Length@{var1} && j > 0) &;
With[{f = Derivative[i, j - 1, k][head]},
 Evaluate@argumentPattern@
    finiteFourierSinTransform := -((n Pi)/(xmax - xmin)) finiteFourierCosTransform[
    f[var1, x, var2], {x, xmin, xmax}, n];
 
 Evaluate@argumentPattern@
    finiteFourierCosTransform := ((n Pi)/(xmax - xmin)) finiteFourierSinTransform[
     f[var1, x, var2], {x, xmin, xmax}, n] + (-1)^n f[var1, xmax, var2] - 
   f[var1, xmin, var2];
 
 Evaluate@argumentPattern@
    finiteFourierTransform := ((2 I n Pi)/(xmax - xmin)) finiteFourierTransform[
     f[var1, x, var2], {x, xmin, xmax}, 
     n] + (-1)^-n (f[var1, xmax, var2] - f[var1, xmin, var2]);
 
 (#[f_ /; AtomQ@f || Quiet@Context@Evaluate@Head[f] === "System`", {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, 
      n_] :=
     With[{assump = {n ∈ Integers, xmax > xmin, #3}, 
       integral = 
        Function[index, 
         Simplify@Integrate[f #2[(index Pi (x - xmin))/(xmax - xmin)], {x, xmin, xmax}]]},
      Module[{general =
         Assuming[assump, integral@n]}, 
       With[{singularity = 
          If[IntegerQ@n, {}, 
           Union@Join[If[#2 === Cos, {0}, {}], 
             Piecewise[{{{}, # === n}}, #] &@(n /. 
                Solve[Flatten@{assump, Denominator@Together@general == 0}, n])]]},
        Piecewise[{integral@#, n == #} & /@ singularity, general]]
       ]
      ]) & @@@ {{finiteFourierSinTransform, Sin, n > 0}, {finiteFourierCosTransform, Cos,
     n >= 0}};
 
 finiteFourierTransform[
   f_ /; AtomQ@f || Quiet@Context@Evaluate@Head[f] === "System`", {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, 
   n_] :=
  With[{assump = {n ∈ Integers, xmax > xmin}, 
    integral = Function[index, 
      Simplify@Integrate[
        f E^(-((2 I index π (x - xmin - (xmax - xmin)/2))/(xmax - xmin))), {x, xmin, 
         xmax}]]},
   Module[{general =
      Assuming[assump, integral@n]}, 
    With[{singularity = 
       If[IntegerQ@n, {}, 
        Piecewise[{{{}, # === n}}, #] &@(n /. 
           Solve[Flatten@{assump, Denominator@Together@general == 0}, n])]},
     Piecewise[{integral@#, n == #} & /@ singularity, general]]
    ]
   ]
 ]


inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[f_, n_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}] := 
 2/(xmax - xmin) HoldForm@Sum[#, {n, C}] &[f Sin[(n Pi (x - xmin))/(xmax - xmin)]]

inverseFiniteFourierCosTransform[f_, n_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}] := 
 1/(xmax - xmin) (f /. n -> 0) + 2/(xmax - xmin) HoldForm@Sum[#, {n, C}] &@
  Simplify[f Cos[(n Pi (x - xmin))/(xmax - xmin)], n > 0]

inverseFiniteFourierTransform[f_, n_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, Re] := 
 1/(xmax - xmin) ((f E^((2 I n π (x - xmin - (xmax - xmin)/2))/(xmax - xmin)) /. 
        n -> 0) + 2 HoldForm@Sum[#, {n, 1, C}] &@
    Simplify[f E^((2 I n π (x - xmin - (xmax - xmin)/2))/(xmax - xmin)) // Re, 
     n ∈ Integers])

inverseFiniteFourierTransform[f_, n_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}] := 
 1/(xmax - xmin) (HoldForm@Sum[#, {n, -C, C}] &@
    Simplify[f E^((2 I n π (x - xmin - (xmax - xmin)/2))/(xmax - xmin)), 
     n ∈ Integers])

transformToIntegrate[expr_] := 
  expr /. (HoldPattern@#[f_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, n_] :> 
        RuleCondition@(HoldForm@Integrate[#, {\[FormalX], xmin, xmax}] &)[
          f #2[(n Pi (x - xmin))/(xmax - xmin)] /. 
           x -> \[FormalX]] & @@@ {{finiteFourierSinTransform, 
        Sin}, {finiteFourierCosTransform, Cos}}) /. 
   HoldPattern@finiteFourierTransform[f_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, n_] :> 
    RuleCondition@(HoldForm@Integrate[#, {\[FormalX], xmin, xmax}] &)@
      Simplify[f E^(-((2 I n π (x - xmin - (xmax - xmin)/2))/(xmax - xmin))) /. 
        x -> \[FormalX], n ∈ Integers];
```

I'm still in *v9* so choose `HoldForm` rather than `Inactivate` to hold the expression.

## Example

Here I'll show the usage of these functions by solving the following initial-boundary value problem (IBVP) which, as far as I can tell, can't be handled by `DSolve` at the moment:

$$u_{t}=\kappa u_{xx}\,, \ \ \ \ \ 0 \leq x \leq a\,,\ \ t>0$$
$$u(0,t)=0=u(a,t)$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)\ \ \text{for}\ 0 \leq x \leq a$$

First, interprete the equation to *Mathematica* code:

```
With[{u = u[t, x]}, eq = D[u, t] == k D[u, x, x];
 ic = {u == f[x] /. t -> 0};
 bc = u == 0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> a}};]
```

Then, use finite Fourier sine transform to eliminate the derivative with respect to $x$. I've used `Format` to make the output better looking:

```
Format@finiteFourierSinTransform[f_, __] := Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalF], s][f]
Format@finiteFourierCosTransform[f_, __] := Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalF], c][f]

finiteFourierSinTransform[{eq, ic}, {x, 0, a}, n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The transformed system involves `u[t, 0]` and `u[t, a]`: they're the boundary condition (b.c.) at hand! So, plug them in:

```
% /. Rule @@@ bc
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the equation becomes an ordinary differential equation (ODE), which can be solved with `DSolve`:

```
tset = % /. HoldPattern@finiteFourierSinTransform[f_ /; ! FreeQ[f, u], __] :> f
tsol = DSolve[tset, u[t, x], t][[1, 1, -1]]
```

> **Remark**

> Notice I've stripped off `finiteFourierSinTransform` before solving
> the ODE because `DSolve` has difficulty in understanding expression
> like `finiteFourierSinTransform[u[t, x], {x, 0, a}, n]`. Just remember
> that `u[t, x]` actually denotes `finiteFourierSinTransform[u[t, x], {x, 0, a}, n]` in `tset`.

The last step is to transform back. You can use `transformToIntegrate` to make `finiteFourierSinTransform` denote as an integration:

```
sol = inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[tsol, n, {x, 0, a}] // transformToIntegrate
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The following is the resulting graph by taking the first 5 terms of the series and choosing $f(x) = x (1 - x), a = 1, \kappa = 1$:

```
Plot3D[Block[{C = 5, f = (# (1 - #) &), a = 1, k = 1, HoldForm = Identity, 
    Sum = Function[{expr, lst}, Total@Table[expr, lst], HoldAll] }, sol] // Evaluate, {t,
   0, 1/2}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Possible issues

1. These functions are built on `Solve`, `Integrate`, etc. so they inherit all their limitations.
2. The singularity test is simple and crude so it will probably fail in complicated cases.
3. The transforms are only suitable for certain types of BVP and IBVP. A typical troublesome case is the 5th exercise in Chapter 10 of [Lokenath Debnath's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1482223570):

$$u_{t}=\kappa u_{xx}\,, \ \ \ \ \ 0 \leq x \leq a\,,\ \ t>0$$
$$u_{x}(0,t)=f(t)$$
$$u_{x}(a,t)+h u(a,t)=0$$
$$u(x,0)=0\ \ \text{for}\ 0 \leq x \leq a$$

For this exercise Lokenath has given the following hint:

> Hint:
> $$\tilde{f}_s(n)=\int_0^a f (x) \sin  (\xi_{n}x) \, dx$$
> $$f(x)=\mathcal{F}_s^{-1} \{\tilde{f}_s(n)\}=\frac{2}{a}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(h^2+\xi_n^2)\tilde{f}_s(n)\sin(x \xi_n)}{h+(h^2+\xi_n^2)}$$
> where $\xi_n$ is the root of the equation $\xi \cot(a \xi)+h=0$.
> $$u(x,t)=(\frac{2}{a})\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\xi_n(h^2+\xi_n^2)}{h+(h^2+\xi_n^2)}\int_0^t f (\xi)\exp[-\kappa \xi_n(t-\xi)]\sin(x \xi_n)\, d\xi$$

The $\tilde{f}_s(n)$ is a general finite Fourier sine transform. ([This paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/43633619) is a possible reference. ) I might implement these transforms someday.

Comment: I tried using this method of Finite fourier transform on a problem I have asked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/two-dimensional-laplacian-coupled-with-another-equation-leading-to-a-bvp-with-in). You have previously answered another question asked by me (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209913/inverse-laplace-transform-of-this-complicated-function)) using this tecnique, so I tried to follow the same steps. It would be great if you could have a look (the first link). My apologies if this specific way of request is outside of the SE ethos.