# how to obtain solution for $u_t+u=u_{xx}$

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I was trying to verify my hand solution for this PDE using Mathematica.

Is a trick to help Mathematica obtain solution to $u_{t}+u=u_{xx}$ with initial conditions $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and boundary conditions $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$ ?

I tried changing $L$ to $1$, and tried using explicit $f(x)$, but Mathematica still can't solve it. This is a basic separation of variables PDE which I think Mathematica 11.2 should have been able to solve it. So I thought may be some one can have a trick to help Mathematica with it.

### Hand solution

Using separation of variables, let $u\left(  x,t\right)  =X\left(  x\right)
T\left(  t\right)  $. Substituting this back into the PDE gives
\begin{align*}
T^{\prime}X+TX &  =X^{\prime\prime}T\\
\frac{T^{\prime}}{T}+1 &  =\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}=-\lambda
\end{align*}
Where the separation constant is some real value $-\lambda$. This gives the
following two ODE's to solve
\begin{align}
T^{\prime}+(1+\lambda)T &  =0\tag{1}\\
X^{\prime\prime}+\lambda X &  =0\tag{2}
\end{align}
Starting with the spatial ODE in order to obtain the eigenvalues. The boundary
conditions on the spatial ODE become
\begin{align*}
X\left(  0\right)   &  =0\\
X\left(  1\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}

The above boundary value ODE is standard one and its eigenvalues are
$$
\lambda_{n}=\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2}\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots
$$
The corresponding eigenfunctions are
$$
X_{n}\left(  x\right)  =c_{n}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
$$

The solution to the time ODE (1) is, using integrating factor method

$$
T\left(  t\right)  =e^{-\left(  1+\lambda_{n}\right)  t}
$$

Therefore
\begin{align}
u\left(  x,t\right)   &  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}\nonumber\\
&  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_{n}\left(  t\right)  X_{n}\left(  x\right)
\nonumber\\
&  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}e^{-\left(  1+\lambda_{n}\right)  t}\sin\left(
\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  \tag{3}
\end{align}

In order to determine $c_{n}$, the initial condition is now applied. At $t=0$,
$u\left(  x,0\right)  =f\left(  x\right)  $ and the above becomes
$$
f\left(  x\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}
}x\right)
$$
Multiplying both sides by $\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{m}}x\right)  $ and
integrating over the domain of $f\left(  x\right)  $ gives
$$
\int_{0}^{L}f\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{m}}x\right)
dx=\int_{0}^{L}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{m}}x\right)  dx
$$
Interchanging the order of summation and integrating gives
$$
\int_{0}^{L}f\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{m}}x\right)
dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\int_{0}^{L}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{m}}x\right)  dx
$$
By orthogonality of $sin$ functions, all terms in the right side vanish except
when $n=m$, leading to
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{L}f\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{m}}x\right)  dx &
=c_{m}\int_{0}^{L}\sin^{2}\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{m}}x\right)  dx\\
&  =c_{m}\frac{L}{2}
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$
c_{m}=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{m}
}x\right)  dx
$$
Since $m$ is an arbitrary number, replacing it back to $n$
\begin{equation}
c_{n}=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}
}x\right)  dx\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots\tag{4}
\end{equation}

But $\sqrt{\lambda_{n}}=\frac{n\pi}{L}$, therefore
$$
c_{n}=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  \frac{n\pi}
{L}x\right)  dx\qquad n=1,2,3,\cdots
$$

The above shows that $c_{n}$ is the Fourier sine series of $f\left(  x\right)
$. Since $f\left(  x\right)  $ is not given, explicit solution for $c_{n}$ can
not be found. Therefore the final solution is

\begin{align*}
u\left(  x,t\right)    & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}e^{-\left(  1+\lambda
_{n}\right)  t}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(  \frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f\left(  x\right)
\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  dx\right)  e^{-\left(  1+\lambda
_{n}\right)  t}\sin\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)
\end{align*}

With $\lambda_{n}=\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2}$.

### Mathematica attempts

```
ClearAll[x, t, u, f];
pde = D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == f[x];
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[L, t] == 0};
DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], x, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[x, t, u, f];
pde = D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == x (1 - x);
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[L, t] == 0};
DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], x, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[x, t, u, f];
pde = D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == x (1 - x);
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[1, t] == 0};
DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], x, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Maple 2017.3 is able to solve this

```
pde:=diff(u(x,t),t)+u(x,t)=diff(u(x,t),x$2);
ic:=u(x,0)=f(x);
bc:=u(0,t)=0,u(L,t)=0;
pdsolve({pde,ic,bc},u(x,t)) assuming L>0;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

May be next version of Mathematica can solve this?

Comment: Is this even general enough to be implemented? This only works for rectangular domains.

Comment: The maple result seems to be hard-coded. You could in principle do the same thing in MMA, but I'm not sure how useful this would be...

Comment: @VsevolodA.  I am not sure I understand your comment. This is 1D problem. What exactly is the `this` when you say "this only works"?

Comment: @Nasser this is 2D domain you are solving PDE in. And "this" is a spectral method, which can also be applied to 3D Possion equation for example (see FFT poisson solver), but only if boundary is rechtangular.

Comment: @VsevolodA. You say "this is 2D domain".  I really thought it was 1D, since domain is $0<x<L$. May be we are using different definition of 1D and 2D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `DSolve` doesn't work well at the moment, you may try [finite Fourier transform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871):

```
(* Definition of finiteFourierSinTransform and finiteFourierCosTransform
   is not included in this post, please find it in the link above. *)
pde = D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == f[x];
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[L, t] == 0};

Format@finiteFourierSinTransform[f_, __] := Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalF], s][f]
Format@finiteFourierCosTransform[f_, __] := Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalF], c][f]

finiteFourierSinTransform[{pde, ic}, {x, 0, L}, n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
% /. Rule @@@ bc
tset = % /. HoldPattern@finiteFourierSinTransform[f_ /; ! FreeQ[f, u], __] :> f;

tsol = DSolve[tset, u[x, t], t][[1, 1, -1]];

sol = inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[tsol, n, {x, 0, L}] // transformToIntegrate
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]