# Laplace PDE inside a disk

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I can't get Mathematica to solve this standard textbook PDE, which is Laplace inside a disk of some radius. One of the boundary conditions needed is that the solution is finite (bounded) in center of disk, and I do not know how specify this boundary condition. I do not know if this is why Mathematica can't solve it. Most examples in help are for `NDSolve` and finite elements, and I am looking to analytical solution.

This is the formal description of the PDE

Solve for $u\left(  r,\theta\right)  $ the PDE

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial
r}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial\theta^{2}}  & =0\\
0  & \leq r\leq a\\
0  & <\theta\leq2\pi
\end{align*}

Boundary conditions

\begin{align*}
u\left(  a,\theta\right)    & =f\left(  \theta\right)  \\
\left\vert u\left(  0,\theta\right)  \right\vert  & <\infty\\
u\left(  r,0\right)    & =u\left(  r,2\pi\right)  \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}\left(  r,0\right)    & =\frac{\partial
u}{\partial\theta}\left(  r,2\pi\right)
\end{align*}

The standard solution using seperation of variables by hand gives

\begin{align*}
u\left(  r,\theta\right)    & =A_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{n}\left(  c_{n}\cos
n\theta+b_{n}\sin n\theta\right)  \\
A_{0}  & =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f\left(  \theta\right)  d\theta\\
c_{n}  & =\frac{1}{\pi a^{n}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f\left(  \theta\right)
\cos\left(  n\theta\right)  d\theta\qquad n>0\\
b_{n}  & =\frac{1}{\pi a^{n}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f\left(  \theta\right)
\sin\left(  n\theta\right)  d\theta\qquad n>0
\end{align*}

This is what I tried

```
ClearAll[u,theta,r,a];
pde=D[u[r,theta],{r,2}]+1/r D[u[r,theta],r]+1/r^2 D[u[r,theta],{theta,2}]==0;
bc=u[a,theta]==f[theta];
sol=DSolve[{pde,bc},u[r,theta],{r,theta},Assumptions->a<r&&a>0&& 0<theta<=2 Pi]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I tried adding the bounded condition, hoping it will help. But I do not know what the syntax should be

```
ClearAll[u,theta,r,a];
pde=D[u[r,theta],{r,2}]+1/r D[u[r,theta],r]+1/r^2 D[u[r,theta],{theta,2}]==0;
bc={u[a,theta]==f[theta],Abs[u[0,theta]]<Infinity}
sol=DSolve[{pde,bc},u[r,theta],{r,theta},Assumptions->a<r&&a>0&& 0<theta<=2 Pi]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ok, so I tried now to add the periodic conditions. But this did not help

```
ClearAll[u,theta,r,a];
pde=D[u[r,theta],{r,2}]+1/r D[u[r,theta],r]+1/r^2 D[u[r,theta],{theta,2}]==0;

bc={u[a,theta]==f[theta],
    u[r,0]==u[r,2 Pi],
    Derivative[0,1][u][r,0]==Derivative[0,1][u][r,2 Pi]}

sol=DSolve[{pde,bc},u[r,theta],{r,theta},Assumptions->a<r&&a>0&& 0<theta<=2 Pi]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question is**: Is Mathematica not able to solve it, because it is missing the bounded conditions part? If so, how to specify this? 
Any one could get Mathematica to solve this analytically?

This is a very standard PDE problem and its analytical solution is all over the net. The above solution I show is the standard text book solution.

11.3 on windows 7

Comment: The Dirichlet  problem under consideration can be solved in Mathematica by making use of Poisson kernel (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel ).

Comment: @user, maybe write an answer demonstrating how to use the Poisson kernel, should you find time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once again, since `DSolve` doesn't work well at the moment, I'd like to post an answer based on [finite Fourier transform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155818/1871):

```
(* Definition of finiteFourierTransform etc. are not included in this post, 
   please find them in the link above. *)
pde = D[u[r, theta], {r, 2}] + 1/r D[u[r, theta], r] + 
    1/r^2 D[u[r, theta], {theta, 2}] == 0;

bc = {u[a, theta] == f[theta], u[r, 0] == u[r, 2 Pi], 
   Derivative[0, 1][u][r, 0] == Derivative[0, 1][u][r, 2 Pi]};

Format@finiteFourierTransform[f_, __] := ℱ[f]
Format@theta := θ

finiteFourierTransform[{pde, bc[[1]]}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We substitute the periodic b.c.s in, and solve the resulting system:

```
% /. Rule @@@ bc[[2 ;; 3]]

tset = % /. HoldPattern@finiteFourierTransform[f_ /; ! FreeQ[f, u], __] :> f
tsol = DSolve[tset, u[r, theta], r][[1, 1, -1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One constant `C[1]` remains, but we still have the bounded condition / finiteness condition at hand. With a bit of transforming:

```
tsolcollect = Collect[Simplify[tsol // TrigToExp, n ∈ Integers], r^_]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It becomes clear that the coefficient of `r^-n` should be `0`, because $\lim_{r\to 0^+} r^{-n}=\infty$ for $n>0$:

```
tsolfinal = tsolcollect /. Flatten@Solve[tsolcollect[[1]] == 0, C[1]] // Simplify
```

The last step is to transform back:

```
sol = inverseFiniteFourierTransform[tsolfinal, n, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, Re]
sol // transformToIntegrate
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

<strike>Though it's troublesome to make *Mathematica* simplify `sol` further,</strike> it's not hard to notice this answer is equivalent to the one in  your question.

`sol` can be used for further calculation of course. For example, when $f=\sin(3\theta)$:

```
ReleaseHold[sol /. f -> (Sin[3 #] &) /. C -> 7 /. a -> 2] // ComplexExpand // Simplify
(* 1/8 r^3 Sin[3 theta] *)
RevolutionPlot3D[%, {r, 0, 2}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sorry, but C -> 7 (as well as several other steps) is built on the sand.

Comment: @user64494 Er… what do you mean by "build on the sand"? Taking the first several terms of a series to approximate its value is a common practice. (`f -> (Sin[3 #] &` happens to be a special case that only `finiteFourierTransform[Sin[3 theta], {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 3]` is non-zero so the final solution is not a series though. )

Answer (score 3):

This is very strange. I suspect Mathematica desktop is being updated/patched from the cloud when one is connected to the internet, because I just tried again the first attempt I showed in my question above and now `DSolve` return the solution to the Laplace PDE !

I do have internet setting in preference to allow Wolfram access to do updates. But I thought this is for documentations and things like that only. I do not understand how this could have happened. But Mathematica 11.3 can actually solve this PDE.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code again (same as in my question)

```
ClearAll[u,theta,r,a];
pde=D[u[r,theta],{r,2}]+1/r D[u[r,theta],r]+1/r^2 D[u[r,theta],{theta,2}]==0;
bc=u[a,theta]==f[theta];
sol=DSolve[{pde,bc},u[r,theta],{r,theta},Assumptions->a<r&&a>0&&0<theta<=2 Pi]
sol=sol/.K[1]->n
```

The third attempt I had in my question, still does not work, but the first works.

I assume someone tried that also and it did not work for them, else they would have screamed at me saying that it works. Very strange. But happy that 11.3 can solve this.