# Problems with DSolve and NDSolve for Dirichlet problem on an annulus

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, symbolic, finite-element-method

To solve the Dirichlet problem on an annulus, I do the following in 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
leqn =  Laplacian[u[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] == 0;
bc1 = u[1, θ] == Sin[θ];
bc2 = u[3, θ] == Sin[6 θ]^2;
sol = DSolve[{leqn, bc1, bc2}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}]
```

and this produces an incorrect result
$$\left\{\left\{u(r,\theta )\to 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{8} \left(\frac{4 \log (r)}{\log (3)}+\left(\frac{9}{r}-r\right) \sin (\theta )\right) & 1\leq r\leq 3 \\
 \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right\}\right\} $$
, whereas it should be
$u \left( r,\theta \right) ={\frac { \left( -531441\,{r}^{24}+531441
 \right) \log  \left( 3 \right) \cos \left( 12\,\theta \right) -
70607384120\,{r}^{11} \left( \sin \left( \theta \right)  \left( {r}^{2
}-9 \right) \log  \left( 3 \right) -4\,r\log  \left( r \right)  \right) 
}{564859072960\,{r}^{12}\log  \left( 3 \right) }}$

The exact solution can be found as a series, following [these lectures](https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/fuchs/PDE14-15/pde14-15-lecture-17.pdf),
but that is a long way.

Let us try the numeric solution of the problem under consideration

```
nsol = NDSolve[{leqn, bc1, bc2}, u, {r, 1, 3}, {θ, 0, 2*Pi}]
(*{{u->InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{1.,3.},{0.,6.28}} Output: scalar ]}}*)
```

Nice. However, when plotting it, one gets face to face with troubles. The command

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r *Cos[θ], r* Sin[θ],Evaluate[u[r, θ] /. nsol]}, {r, 1, 3}, {θ, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

produces an empty plot, the commands

```
ListPlot3D[Partition[Flatten[Table[{r*Cos[θ], r*Sin[θ], 
 u[r, θ] /. nsol},{r, 1, 3, 0.05},{θ, N[0, 25], 
 N[2*Pi, 25], N[2*Pi, 25]/120}]], 3]]
```

[image]
and

```
ListPointPlot3D[Partition[Flatten[Table[{r*Cos[θ], r*Sin[θ], 
 u[r, θ] /. nsol}, {r, 1, 3, 0.05}, {θ, N[0, 25], 
 N[2*Pi, 25], N[2*Pi, 25]/120}]], 3]]
```

[image]

work, but these show a break at the ray $\theta=0$ (Indeed, `u[2., 0.01] /. nsol` performs `{0.454836}`
and `u[2., 6.28 - 0.01] /. nsol` results in `{0.168936}`.),
whereas the solution is a twice-differentiable function on the annulus. The change of the interval `{θ, 0, 2*Pi}` by `{θ, -Pi, Pi}`
does not help.

My questions are: can the exact solution in a series form be transformed to a closed-form expression?
can the break of the numeric solution be removed by options of `NDSolve`?

Comment: You need to add the periodic b.c. in $\theta$ direction.

Comment: @xzczd: Can you elaborate your comment? TIA.

Comment: @xzczd: Both `bc1` and `bc2`are periodic functions with period `2*Pi`. Are you serious?

Comment: Of course I'm serious. `bc1` and `bc2` only indicate the solution is periodic at $r=1$ and $r=3$.

Comment: @xzczd: Up to the cited lectures and other sources, the Drichlet problem on an annulus  with periodic smooth boundary conditions has the twice-differentiable solution. In the case under consideration this is $u \left( r,\theta \right) ={\frac { \left( -531441\,{r}^{24}+531441
 \right) \log  \left( 3 \right) \cos \left( 12\,\theta \right) -
70607384120\,{r}^{11} \left( \sin \left( \theta \right)  \left( {r}^{2
}-9 \right) \log  \left( 3 \right) -4\,r\log  \left( r \right)  \right) 
}{564859072960\,{r}^{12}\log  \left( 3 \right) }}$.

Comment: xzczd's point is that you only told `NDSolve[]` that your function over an annulus is periodic at the boundaries, but not within the annulus itself.

Comment: @J.M: Can you indicate how to do that?

Comment: The result of `NDSolve[{leqn, DirichletCondition[{bc1, bc2}, True]}, u, {r, 1, 
  3}, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}]` is also  unsatisfactory.

Comment: I was also not able to get a satisfactory answer from NDSolve. Perhaps you should mail the problem to "support@wolfram.com". It would be helpful if you could post their answer here.

Comment: It should be noticed if `bc2` is replaced by `bc3 = u[3, \[Theta]] == Sin[6 \[Theta]];`, then `DSolve` produces the correct solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

3 issues here, I'll start from the simplest one.

First of all, to solve the problem inside an annulus, you need to *tell* `NDSolve` you're solving inside an annulus in some way. The simplest approach is to stay in Cartesian coordinate and choose a `Annulus[…]` region:

```
nsolref = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Sin[ArcTan[x, y]], x^2 + y^2 == 1], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Sin[6 ArcTan[x, y]]^2, x^2 + y^2 == 3^2]}, 
  u, {x, y} ∈ Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 3}]]

Plot3D[nsolref[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 3}], PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

If you want to stay in polar coordinate, you need to tell `NDSolve` the region is periodic in $\theta$ direction, and here comes the second issue. As discussed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220363/1871), we need to use `TriangleElement` and add 2 `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[……]` to `NDSolve` to keep the derivative periodic:

```
nsol = NDSolveValue[{leqn, bc1, bc2, 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[r, θ], θ == 2 π && 1 < r < 3, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, -2 Pi}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[r, θ], θ == 0 && 1 < r < 3, 
    TranslationTransform[{0, 2 Pi}]]}, u, {r, 1, 3}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Method -> {FiniteElement, 
    MeshOptions -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001, MeshElementType -> TriangleElement}}]

RevolutionPlot3D[nsol[r, th], {r, 1, 3}, {th, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

As to the analytic solution, it's a pity `DSolve` can't solve the problem at the moment:

```
DSolve[{leqn, bc1, bc2, u[r, 0] == u[r, 2 Pi]}, 
 u[r, θ], {r, 1, 3}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]
(* Input returned. *)
```

So I'll use the [finite Fourier transform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155818/1871) to solve the problem as I've done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/168136/1871). If you still think this method is *built on the sand*, please ignore this part of the answer:

```
generateteq[n_] := 
 finiteFourierTransform[{leqn, bc1, bc2}, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, n] /. 
    a_[r, 0] -> a[r, 2 Pi] /. finiteFourierTransform[a_, __] -> a /. u -> (U[#] &)

teqgeneral = generateteq[n]    
tsolgeneral = DSolveValue[teqgeneral, U[r], r, Assumptions -> n > 0]

teq0 = generateteq[0]    
tsol0 = DSolveValue[teq0, U[r], r]

teq1 = generateteq[1]    
tsol1 = DSolveValue[teq1, U[r], r]

teq12 = generateteq[12]    
tsol12 = DSolveValue[teq12, U[r], r]

asol[r_, θ_] = 
 inverseFiniteFourierTransform[
      Piecewise[{{tsol0, n == 0}, {tsol1, n == 1}, {tsol12, n == 12}}], 
      n, {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, Re] /. C -> 12 // ReleaseHold // ComplexExpand // 
  Simplify[#, r > 0] &
(*
-((531441 (-1 + r^24) Cos[12 θ])/(564859072960 r^12)) + Log[r]/
 Log[9] - ((-9 + r^2) Sin[θ])/(8 r)
 *)
ref[r_, θ_] = ((531441 - 531441 r^24) Cos[12 θ] Log[3] - 
    70607384120 r^11 (-4 r Log[r] + (-9 + r^2) Log[
         3] Sin[θ]))/(564859072960 r^12 Log[3])

asol[r, th] == ref[r, th] // Simplify
(* True *)
```

In this method, the finite Fourier transforms of `{leqn, bc1, bc2}` when $n=0,1,12$ are calculated separately, because `finiteFourierTransform`, which is based on `Integrate`, isn't able to handle these special cases properly, at least up to *v12.2*. (Still confused? Just observe the output of `Integrate[Sin[x] Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]`. )

Finally, a comparison for the 4 solutions:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{nsol[r, θ], nsolref[r Cos@θ, r Sin@θ] + 0.01, 
   asol[r, θ] + 0.02, ref[r, θ] + 0.03}, {r, 1, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> 1], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

---

### Update

Just find something funny. If we transform `bc2` with `TrigReduce`:

```
bc2 = u[3, θ] == Sin[6 θ]^2 // TrigReduce
(* u[3, θ] == 1/2 (1 - Cos[12 θ]) *)
```

`DSolve` finds the *desired* result, at least in *v12.2*:

```
sol = DSolve[{leqn, bc1, bc2}, u[r, θ], {r, θ}, Assumptions -> 1 <= r <= 3][[1]]
(*
{u[r, θ] -> -((531441 (-1 + r^24) Cos[12 θ])/(564859072960 r^12)) + Log[r]/
   Log[9] - ((-9 + r^2) Sin[θ])/(8 r)}
 *)
```

However, this may be a coincidence. Though not explicitly documented, according to the examples in the document of `DSolve`, when b.c. in certain direction is missing, it seems that `DSolve` will simply assume the problem is defined in an unbounded domain i.e. perhaps `DSolve` has assumed $θ∈(−∞,+∞)$ in this case.

Let's verify the guess. Suppose $θ∈(−∞,+∞)$ and the solution is finite, then a standard technique to eliminate derivative of $\theta$ is to apply `FourierTransform` in $\theta$ direction. I'll use the `ft` defined in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871) to facilitate the coding:

```
(* Definition of ft isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
tset = ft[{leqn, bc1, bc2}, θ, w] /. HoldPattern@FourierTransform[a_, __] :> a

tsol = DSolve[tset, u[r, θ], r][[1, 1, -1]]

solFourier = 
 1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Integrate[tsol Exp[-I w θ], {w, -Infinity, Infinity}] // FullSimplify

(*
1/8 ((4 Log[r])/Log[3] + (9/r - r) Sin[θ] - 
   4 Cos[12 θ] Csch[12 Log[3]] Sinh[12 Log[r]])
 *)

ref[r, θ] == solFourier // Simplify
(* True *)
```

I've used `Integrate` instead of `InverseFourierTransform` to calculate the inverse Fourier transform, because `tsol` triggers a bug of `InverseFourierTransform`, at least in *v12.2*.

As we can see, in this case the solution in unbounded domain happens to be the same as that determined by periodic b.c.. Not sure if there's a deeper reason for the coincidence, though.

Comment: xzczd (@ does not work.) +1. Many thanks from me to you for your skillful work.

Comment: It should be noticed if `bc2` is replaced by `bc3 = u[3, \[Theta]] == Sin[6 \[Theta]];`, then `DSolve` produces the correct solution.

Comment: @user64494 May be a coincidence. Though not explicitly documented, according to the examples in the document of `DSolve`, when b.c. in certain direction is missing, it seems that `DSolve` will simply assume the problem is defined in an unbounded domain i.e. in this case `DSolve` probably assumes $\theta \in (-\infty, +\infty)$. Perhaps for `bc3`, the solution in unbounded domain happens to be the same as that determined by periodic b.c..

Comment: @xzczd It is nice solution (+1). It looks like we discussed this problem several times.

Comment: @AlexTrunev: Can you give references? TIA.

Comment: @xzczd: You wrote "May be a coincidence". I don't thnik so: `DSolve` correctly solves many other Dirichlet problems on an annulus.

Comment: @user64494 Alex is probably refering to the `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[…]` issue, and the first link in my answer is the best reference so far. Sadly nobody has managed to explain why the combination of `TriangleElement` and 2 `PeriodicBoundaryCondition[……]` works at the moment.

Comment: @user64494 I find something funny. Have a look at the update.