# Laplacian and NDSolve and DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am trying to solve a simple test example using `Laplacian`. But I step from one problem to the next.

First I did not realized, that MMA uses spherical coordinates in the order: r,theta,phi and not, as I was accustomed to: r,phi,theta. Now as this is corrected, I get a constant instead of the expected function:

Consider a unit sphere having an electrostatic potential of 1. It is well know that the potential in the 3D charge free outside this sphere is 1/r.

Using `Laplacian` in spherical coordinates, this can be written by:

```
Clear[sol, f, r, ph, th]
rmax = 10;
sol[r_, th_, ph_] = 
 f[r, th, ph] /. 
  NDSolve[{Laplacian[f[r, th, ph], {r, th, ph}, "Spherical"] == 0, 
     f[1, th, ph] == 1}, 
    f, {r, 1, rmax}, {th, 0, Pi}, {ph, -Pi, Pi}][[1]]
Plot[{sol[r, 0, 0], 1/r}, {r, 1, rmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Instead of 1/r I get a constant of 1, independent of rmax.

Further, if I give a periodic boundary condition., MMA complains about an "overdetermined system". And MMA can not do the calculation with increased working precision.

`DSolve` does not even give a result, it simply gives the equation back.

**Update:**

As xzczd remarked, if no boundary condition at infinity is given, MMA assumes Neumann conditions, that is it sets the derivatives to zero, what then gives a constant for the solution.

Therefore I choose rmax =100 (large enough) and specify `` f[rmax, th, ph] == 0`:

```
Clear[sol, f, r, ph, th]
rmax = 100;
sol[r_, th_, ph_] = 
 f[r, th, ph] /. 
  NDSolve[{Laplacian[f[r, th, ph], {r, th, ph}, "Spherical"] == 0, 
     f[1, th, ph] == 1, f[rmax, th, ph] == 0}, 
    f, {r, 1, rmax}, {th, 0, Pi}, {ph, -Pi, Pi}][[1]]
Plot[{sol[r, 0, 0], 1/r}, {r, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now we at least get something similar to 1/r.

Uff.., earning is hard, but it is better to look like a fool for a short time than being one for the rest of ones life.

Comment: You'd need to specify bounds for the independent variables, like `{r, 0, 1}, {ph, 0, \[Pi]}, {th, 0, \[Pi]}`

Comment: Also, you need periodic b.c. One example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239239/1871

Comment: @user21 Thanks', I knew that I made a stupid error.  However, things get even worse when MMA does some evaluation. I changed my question accordingly.

Comment: It should be `{ph, 0, Pi}, {th, -Pi, Pi}`. Please check the definition of `"Spherical"` coordinates in _Mathematica_ carefully.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks a lot. I corrected this, but now I get a constant instead of 1/r. It is sort of embarrassing, but I want to understand how to use the `Laplacian` operator in MMA.

Comment: The constant solution is expected, because you haven't set b.c. at `rmax` to approximate b.c. at infinity, so `FiniteElement` method by default uses zero Neumann value as the b.c., which leads to the solution $f=1$. A possible b.c. at `rmax` is `DirichletCondition[f[r, th, ph] == 0, r == rmax && -Pi < ph < Pi]`, you need to make `rmax` large enough, though.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks again, without some hints, I would not get anywhere. Now it starts to resemble 1/r.  But it is astonishing that `DSolve` can not deal with this simplest of a test example.

Comment: If you only care about the spherically symmetric case, directly solve the ODE will be the easiest: `Limit[DSolveValue[{Laplacian[f[r], {r, th, ph}, "Spherical"] == 0, f[1] == 1, 
   f[inf] == 0}, f[r], r], inf -> Infinity]`

Comment: @ xzczd I want to learn how to use the `Laplacian` operator. The spherically symmetric case  was only a simple test example.