# why can't Mathematica solve the wave PDE on string when adding a dispersion term?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

Could someone possibly gives an insight as to why `DSolve` can solve

$$
\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}=\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}
}\qquad t>0
$$

But not this very similar PDE

$$
\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}+u=\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}
}\qquad t>0
$$

Since the process of solving these by separation of variables is almost
identical. In the second PDE, the time ODE to solve is $T^{\prime\prime
}+\left(  1+n^{2}\right)  T=0$ while in the first PDE the time ODE to solve
is $T^{\prime\prime}+n^{2}T=0$. Everything else is the same.

So I am baffled why Mathematica can solve one PDE
but not the other. I thought if one can understand better why it could not solve it, that will be useful thing to know when trying other problems by knowing better what are the limitation they should expect in advance.

So this question is asking to find why it could not solve it. I know this might be hard for users since we have no access to the source code. Also if someone can show a workaround, to solve this, using `DSolve` that will be accepted also.

Here is analytical solution to the second PDE (the one that can't be solved by Mathematica).

Here is analytical solution to the first one.

Solve, $0<x<\pi$

$$
\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}+u=\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}
}\qquad t>0
$$

Boundary conditions, $t>0$ (both ends fixed)

\begin{align*}
u\left(  0,t\right)   &  =0\\
u\left(  \pi,t\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}

Initial conditions, $t=0$

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u\left(  x,0\right)  }{\partial t}  &  =0\\
u\left(  x,0\right)   &  =\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)
\end{align*}

Analytical solution:

Dispersion term $u$ causes the shape of the original wave to distort with
time. Using separation of variables, Let $u=X\left(  x\right)  T\left(
t\right)  .$ Substituting this back in the PDE gives

\begin{align*}
T^{\prime\prime}X+XT  &  =X^{\prime\prime}T\\
\frac{T^{\prime\prime}}{T}+1  &  =\frac{X^{\prime\prime}}{X}=-\lambda
\end{align*}

The eigenvalue ODE\ is

\begin{align*}
X^{\prime\prime}+\lambda X  &  =0\\
X\left(  0\right)   &  =0\\
X\left(  \pi\right)   &  =0
\end{align*}

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{n}=\left(  \frac{n\pi}{L}\right)  ^{2}
,n=1,2,3,\cdots$ and $L=\pi$ here, then $\lambda_{n}=n^{2}$ and the
eigenfunctions are $X_{n}\left(  x\right)  =c_{n}\sin\left(  nx\right)  $. The
time ODE\ becomes

\begin{align*}
T^{\prime\prime}+\left(  1+\lambda_{n}\right)  T  &  =0\\
T^{\prime\prime}+\left(  1+n^{2}\right)  T  &  =0
\end{align*}

The roots of the characteristic equation are $\pm i\sqrt{1+n^{2}}$, since
$n^{2}\geq1$. Hence the solution of the above ODE\ is

$$
T_{n}\left(  t\right)  =A_{n}\cos\left(  t\sqrt{1+n^{2}}\right)  +B_{n}
\sin\left(  t\sqrt{1+n^{2}}\right)
$$

Taking time derivatives gives

$$
T_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  =-\sqrt{1+n^{2}}A_{n}\sin\left(
t\sqrt{1+n^{2}}\right)  +B_{n}\sqrt{1+n^{2}}\cos\left(  t\sqrt{1+n^{2}
}\right)
$$

At time $t=0$, the above is zero (initial velocity is zero), which gives

$$
0=B_{n}\sqrt{1+n^{2}}
$$

Hence $B_{n}=0$ and the time ODE solution becomes

$$
T_{n}\left(  t\right)  =A_{n}\cos\left(  t\sqrt{1+n^{2}}\right)
$$

Hence the fundamental solution is

\begin{align*}
u_{n}\left(  x,t\right)   &  =T_{n}X_{n}\\
&  =c_{n}\overset{T_{n}}{\overbrace{\cos\left(  t\sqrt{1+n^{2}}\right)  }
}\overset{X_{n}}{\overbrace{\sin\left(  nx\right)  }}
\end{align*}

Where constant $A_{n}$ merged with $c_{n}$. Therefore the solution is

$$
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\cos\left(  t\sqrt{1+n^{2}
}\right)  \sin\left(  nx\right)
$$

$c_{n}$ is found from initial position. At $t=0$ the above becomes

$$
\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\sin\left(  nx\right)
$$

Applying orthogonality gives

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  nx\right)  dx=c_{n}
\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

For $n=2,\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  2x\right)  dx=0$,
hence $c_{2}=0$ and for $n\neq2$

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(  nx\right)  dx &
=c_{n}\frac{\pi}{2}\\
c_{n} &  =\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\left(  x\right)  \sin\left(
nx\right)  dx\\
&  =\frac{2}{\pi}\left(  \frac{2\left(  \cos\left(  \pi n\right)  -1\right)
}{n^{3}-4n}\right)  \\
c_{n} &  =\frac{4\left(  \left(  -1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)  }{\pi n\left(
n^{2}-4\right)  }\qquad n\neq2
\end{align*}

Hence solution is

\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1,3,4,\cdots}^{\infty}\frac{4\left(  \left(
-1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)  }{\pi n\left(  n^{2}-4\right)  }\cos\left(
t\sqrt{1+n^{2}}\right)  \sin\left(  nx\right)  \tag{1}
\end{equation}

We see that only difference between the solution to
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}+u=\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}
}\qquad t>0
$$

And

$$
\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}=\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}
}\qquad t>0
$$

Is just the solution of \ $T^{\prime\prime}+\left(  1+n^{2}\right)  T=0$ vs.
$T^{\prime\prime}+n^{2}T=0$. Repeating the above separation of variables for
$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}=\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}$
gives the solution

\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=1,3,4,\cdots}^{\infty}\frac{4\left(  \left(
-1\right)  ^{n}-1\right)  }{\pi n\left(  n^{2}-4\right)  }\cos\left(
nt\right)  \sin\left(  nx\right)  \tag{2}
\end{equation}

So why did Mathematica solve (2) but not (1)?

### Code

```
ClearAll[u,x,t];
pde=D[u[x,t],{t,2}]==D[u[x,t],{x,2}];
bc={u[0,t]==0,u[Pi,t]==0};
ic={Derivative[0,1][u][x,0]==0,u[x,0]==Sin[x]^2};
sol=DSolve[{pde,bc,ic},u[x,t],{x,t}];
sol=sol/.K[1]->n
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now add dispersion term

```
ClearAll[u,x,t];
pde=D[u[x,t],{t,2}]+ u[x,t]==D[u[x,t],{x,2}];
bc={u[0,t]==0,u[Pi,t]==0};
ic={Derivative[0,1][u][x,0]==0,u[x,0]==Sin[x]^2};
sol=DSolve[{pde,bc,ic},u[x,t],{x,t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using 11.3 on windows

**Update**

Added verification by comparing to numerical solution.

[image]

Code for the above

```
pde = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + u[x, t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = {u[x, 0] == Sin[x]^2, Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0};
bc = {u[0, t] == 0, u[Pi, t] == 0};
numericalSol = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 10}];

cn[n_] := If[n == 2, 0, (4 ((-1)^n - 1))/(Pi n (n^2 - 4))];
mySolution[x_, t_] := Sum[cn[n] Cos[t Sqrt[1 + n^2]] Sin[n x], {n, 1, 20}];

Manipulate[
 opt = {GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 300};

 Grid[{
   {Row[{"time ", t}], SpanFromLeft},
   {Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. numericalSol], {x, 0, Pi}, 
     PlotLabel -> "NDSolve", ImageSize -> 300, Evaluate@opt],
    Plot[mySolution[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotLabel -> "Analytical", 
     PlotStyle -> Red, Evaluate@opt]}
   }, Spacings -> {1, 1}, Alignment -> Center],
 {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 10, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t}
 ]
```

Here is the same plot, but on top of each others. They are an exact match

[image]

Code for above is

```
Manipulate[
 opt = {GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> 300};

 p1 = Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. numericalSol], {x, 0, Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> 300, Evaluate@opt, PlotStyle -> Blue];
 p2 = Plot[mySolution[x, t], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red, Evaluate@opt];

 Grid[{
   {Row[{"time ", t}], SpanFromLeft},
   {Show[p1, p2]}
   }, Spacings -> {1, 1}, Alignment -> Center],
 {{t, 0, "time"}, 0, 10, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t}
 ]
```

Comment: A bit of spelunking shows a ``DSolve`DSolveWaveEquation`` function is called, and this function can only solve the 1st `pde`…

Comment: Probably limitation. Nothing is perfect.

Comment: I'm surprised that it is solving PDE in analytical form at all.

Comment: What about second terms in formulas (1) and (2) ?, $\;c_2=?$
My solution of the problem $\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial t^{2}}+u=\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}
}\quad t>0,\quad 0<x<\pi$ $u\left( 0,t\right)=0,\quad u\left( \pi,t\right)=0,\quad t>0$ $\frac{\partial u\left( x,0\right) }{\partial t} =0,\quad
u\left( x,0\right)=\sin^{2}\left( x\right),\quad 0<x<\pi$ is $u=-\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }{\left. \frac{\cos{\left( \sqrt{{{\left( 2 n-1\right) }^{2}}+1}\, t\right) } \sin{((2n-1)x)}}{(2n-3)\,(2n-1)\,(2n+1)}\right.}$

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas You're right, the analytic solution given by Nasser is incorrect (at the moment), the $c_2$ term needs to be discussed separately. The solution given by you seems to be correct, and based on [`finiteFourierSinTransform`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155818/1871), I found the solution can be expressed as `(2*HoldForm[Sum[((1/2)*(1 + E^(2*Sqrt[-1 - n^2]*t))*Piecewise[{{0, n == 2}}, (2*(-1 + (-1)^n))/(-4*n + n^3)]*Sin[n*x])/
            E^(Sqrt[-1 - n^2]*t), {n, Infinity}]])/Pi`, which seems to be equivalent to yours. (I've compared them to `NDSolve` result. )

Comment: @AleksasDomarkas and  xzczd. I needed to use the sqrt of of the eigenvalue for $X_n$, i.e. use $n$ instead of $n^2$ that is all. I fixed it now. Thanks for pointing this out  :) I can't read the latex you posted in your comment. But I think my solution is now correct.

Comment: @xzczd I compared it to numerical NDSolve, I get exact match using only 20 terms in sum. Please see update.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unlike integration and even--to a lesser extent--ODEs, in which there are computationally tracktable algorithms for computing answers for broad classes of functions, there aren't really such methods for PDEs.  So DSolve must essentially reduce the input a to known template in order to solve it.  Apparently we're missing the template for linear dispersion.  I will pass this along to the relevant team.