# How to obtain the exact solution of a partial differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I know that Mathematica can solve a PDE numerically, but I wonder if it is possible to obtain the exact solution. For example, consider the heat equation

$$u_t = \kappa u_{xx} $$

Is it possible to solve it with a set of initial and boundary conditions to calculate the exact equation of $u$

$$u = f(x,t)$$
and
$$u(x=0) = f(t)$$

I don't need numeral solution or the graph but the general equations.

**EXAMPLE**

One dimensional heat flow in an slab, one side is insulated and the other side at a constant flux of heat

$$ u(x,0) = U\\ u_x(0,t) = 0\\ u_x(L,t) = T $$

The solution is available from the textbooks. I just wonder, if Mathematica can give us the solution, as we can slightly alter the conditions to find new solutions.

Comment: That depends really on the domain. For example, the fundamental solution for the disk is known and the symbolic solution can be obtained via convolution with it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I am interested in the boundary conditions rather than domain. I would consider one-dimensional. It may seem strange, but I am interested to find the solution by Laplance transformation or so. I add an example.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, and be specific, **include minimal working example of code and data you have tried** in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you can solve pde's symbollically.

example heat equation:

```
DSolve[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] == Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t],u[0, t] == f[t]}, u, {x, t}][[1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

The specific example can be solved with the help of [finite Fourier cosine transform and its inversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871):

```
With[{u = u[t, x]},
 eq = D[u, t] == κ D[u, x, x];
 ic = u == U[x] /. t -> 0;
 bc = {D[u, x] == 0 /. x -> 0, D[u, x] == T /. x -> L};]

Format@finiteFourierSinTransform[f_, __] := Subscript[ℱ, s][f]
Format@finiteFourierCosTransform[f_, __] := Subscript[ℱ, c][f]

help[index_] := 
 Module[{tset = 
    finiteFourierCosTransform[{eq, ic}, {x, 0, L}, index] /. Rule @@@ bc /. 
     HoldPattern@finiteFourierCosTransform[f_ /; ! FreeQ[f, u], __] :> f},
  tsol = DSolve[tset, u[t, x], t][[1, 1, -1]]]

tsolgeneral = help[n]

tsolzero = help[0]

tsolfunc[n_] = Piecewise[{{tsolgeneral, n != 0}}, tsolzero]

sol = inverseFiniteFourierCosTransform[tsolfunc[n], n, {x, 0, L}] // transformToIntegrate
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's check the solution numerically with $U=x(1-x),\ L=1,\ κ = 1,\ T = 1$:

```
U = (# (1 - #) &); L = 1; κ = 1; T = 1;
nsol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 1/10}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 5000}}];

With[{expr = 
   Block[{C = 20, HoldForm = Identity, 
     Sum = Function[{expr, lst}, Total@Table[expr, lst], HoldAll]}, sol]}, 
 Manipulate[Plot[{expr, nsol[t, x]}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All], {t, 0, 1/10}]]
Clear[U, L, κ, T]
```

[image]

**Remark**

1. Finite Fourier Cosine transform at $n=0$ is calculated separately here because currently `finiteFourierCosTransform` cannot handle the singularity at $n=0$ properly.
2. The reason why `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"` option is added is explained in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127411/1871).

Comment: don't you get the error, `NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.`?

Comment: @Googlebot It doesn't matter as long as `"DifferentiateBoundaryConditions"` option is properly set. For more information you can check the last link in my answer.